# How to get a selected column's data in a string from the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, binding

I am binding data in Gridview control in page load event.

How to get a selected column's data in a string from the Gridview control?

(ie)It is the primary key of that table,so for every row selected by user there will be a primary key ID column bounded to it. So I need to get that ID & with this ID, I need to link with the next page of my web application.

Using Visual Studio 2005 asp.net C# 2.0.

Below is some of the code what I tried :

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string bS = Convert.ToString(gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text);
}
```

Comment: use the SelectedRow property of your gridView. Following link have some ways to get your job done with better explanation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx

Comment: Post your gridview code !There are many options you can use for say Selected Row property , RowCommand etc .

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

**EDIT**

Add a hidden field to your markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
... ... ...   ... ... ...   ... ... ...   ... ... ...
```

On GridVew's selectedIndexChanged event, set the vallue to hidden field:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    hdnID.Value = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

In button event get the value from hidden field:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bS = hdnID.Value;
}
```

Comment: this code fetches every values of required column instead of only one value of the selected row alone in gridview

Comment: Yeah, this is what I generally do. I've even got a few with check boxes and loop through the grid grabbing only the names in the checked boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RowCommand` event. Below is a sample from my code. You should use `DataKey`s to provide a button field in `GridView` and give `CommandName = Select`.

```
   protected void GridView_AccGroups_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.CommandName == "Select")   //commandName given to the button field in the Gridview
       {

            foreach (GridViewRow i in GridView_AccGroups.Rows)   //takes each Gridview Row..my Gridview name is 'GridView_AccGroups'
            {
                try
                {
                    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    // gets the selected Index
                    GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView_AccGroups.Rows[index];  // with the selected index gets the selected Row 
                    string txtAccGroupName = GridView_AccGroups.DataKeys[index].Values["Account Group"].ToString();  // DataKey Names are given in the Gridview Properties..!! each key name in one line,these key names are column names in the result of the select query that is bound to the Gridview,
                    string txtAccGroupShortName = GridView_AccGroups.DataKeys[index].Values["Short Name"].ToString();

                    string  txtAccGroupRemarks = GridView_AccGroups.DataKeys[index].Values["Remarks"].ToString();
                    string id = GridView_AccGroups.DataKeys[index].Values["ID"].ToString();

                    string = GridView_AccGroups.DataKeys[index].Values["Parent Group ID"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }          
    }
```